# Backbone/Marionette/browserify – Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, browserify

I recently upgraded npm and node, only to have some serious problems with my browserify setup. Requiring Marionette results in a this build error, presumable because Backbone jQuery is not defined.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Deferred' of undefined
```

Here is how I am requiring Marionette, Backbone and jquery:

```
var Modernizr = require('Modernizr');
var jQuery = require('jquery');
var Underscore = require('underscore');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Moment = require('moment');


Backbone.$ = jQuery;
require('backbone.marionette');
require('backbone.babysitter');
require('backbone.wreqr');
```

Here is is my package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.2.0",
    "backbone.babysitter": "^0.1.6",
    "backbone.marionette": "^2.4.1",
    "backbone.wreqr": "^1.3.1",
    "browserify": "^10.2.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.7",
    "connect": "^3.3.5",
    "d3": "^3.5.5",
    "deamdify": "^0.1.1",
    "debowerify": "^1.2.1",
    "decomponentify": "^0.1.0",
    "deglobalify": "^0.2.0",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-flatten": "0.0.4",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-include": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-open": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-streamify": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "handlebars": "^3.0.3",
    "hbsfy": "^2.2.1",
    "imagesloaded": "^3.1.8",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "node-bourbon": "^4.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.1.2",
    "numeral": "^1.5.3",
    "spin.js": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browser": {
    "Modernizr": "./src/javascript/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "Modernizr": {
      "exports": "Modernizr"
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "hbsfy",
      "debowerify",
      "decomponentify",
      "deamdify",
      "deglobalify",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
```

I am really at a loss as to what is causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the latest version of Backbone breaking Marionette.

Using Backbone v1.1.2 until Marionette releases an update should solve it.

Here's the github issue for reference https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/2559